# unable to receive xml response from SOAP web service using CRON

Tags: php, soap, cron

I have a function which handles the SOAP based web service.

When I run the function via URL I am getting XML response. but when I run the function through CRON I am not getting xml response.

```
<?php

$logFile = 'checking'.date('Y-m-d').'.log';

        $client = new SoapClient("http://DOMAIN/services/weburl?wsdl",array( "trace" => true, 'use' => SOAP_LITERAL));
        $params = array('username' => 'username', 'Password' => 'password', 'delatdate' => '17/06/2015 18:00:00');
        try{
            $response = $client>-productOnHand($params);


        } catch(SoapFault $e){
            echo $e->faultcode; echo '<br />';
            echo $e->getMessage(); echo '<br />';
        }

        require_once 'app/Mage.php';
        Mage::app();

        Mage::log(print_r($response, true), null, $logFile);
        Mage::log(print_r($client->__getLastResponse(), true), null, $logFile);

?>
```

If I run this web page via URL I am getting valid xml response. But when this page is being called through CRON I am not getting valid response.

Comment: What are you getting  when you run it from cron? Is there any error?

Comment: @AlexBlex I am not getting any error. In the mean time I am getting no response. But if I run through browser I am getting some thing like `stdClass Object
(
    [return] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><products......`

Comment: If you have no errors, nor responses, how do you know your cron job started at all?

Comment: @AlexBlex I created a log inside the cron function it captures the request I send and print response as ''

Comment: Could you add this code to the question? Ensure `error_reporting(E_ALL);` either in your code or in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue.

Before `default_socket_timeout` was set as 60. I raised it as 600. Now I could able to receive.